# How can I upload a picture to AWS Cognito using Amplify?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify in Angular and can't seem to find a way to set the picture attribute. All other attributes work OK

```
      Auth.completeNewPassword(
        user,
        this.profileForm.get('newPassword')?.value,
        {
          "phone_number": String(this.profileForm.get('phone')?.value),
          "given_name": this.profileForm.get('fName')?.value,
          "family_name": this.profileForm.get('lName')?.value,
          "locale": this.profileForm.get('language')?.value,
          "picture": // How do I set this with a file uploader input?
        }
      )
      .then(data => console.log("Changed Password! -->", data))
      .catch(err => console.log("Password change failed: ", err));
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I dropped this after. Sorry